# Consulta varias tablas mysql con próximos clientes a cobrar y agregar al small box

Tags: mysql

hola soy novato es este mundo de laravel, tengo varias tablas distintas la cual integro a una principal

```
Tabla Credito (esta es la tabla principal)

        $table->string('clientes')->nullable();
        $table->string('creditosnumero')->nullable();
        $table->double('total');

Tabla clientes

        $table->string('codigo')->nullable();
        $table->string('nombre')->nullable();
        $table->string('departamento')->nullable();
        $table->string('ciudad')->nullable();
        $table->string('direccion')->nullable();
        $table->string('telefono')->nullable();
        $table->string('numerotalonario')->nullable();
        $table->string('fotopagare')->nullable();
        $table->string('correo')->nullable();

Tabla abono_detail

        $table->integer('abonos_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('tipoabono_id')->nullable();
        $table->double('abonoprecio');
        $table->integer('abonofecha')->nullable();
        $table->integer('abonocantidad')->default(0);
        $table->double('sub_total');

Tabla creditos_detail

        $table->integer('creditos_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('productos_id')->nullable();
        $table->double('precio');
        $table->integer('cantidad')->default(0);
        $table->double('sub_total');
```

hasta hay todo funciona bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi inquietud es la siguiente: como hago una consulta a las tablas pero solo quiero mostrar el

```
    $table->string('clientes')->nullable();
    $table->string('creditosnumero')->nullable();
    $table->double('abonoprecio');
    $table->integer('abonofecha')->nullable();
```

pero que me muestre las de un día siguiente hasta 7 días después dependiendo "abonofecha" para ellos estoy utilizando esto un "small box"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no tengo idea que debo de poner hay

Información adicional

los formularios funcionado correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a que esta el mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a mi criterio, estan mal diseñadas tus tablas, pues si guardan relación entre ellas, veo que declaras unas que parecen llaves primarias pero no veo donde las vincules con sus respectivas tablas

Comment: hay esta funcionado bien, hay te publico los pantallas, aunque la fecha me falta modificar por formato de fecha es lo único mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya e encontrado la solución

```
Agregado una Tabla Nueva
        $table->integer('fee_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('tipodepago_id')->nullable();
        $table->double('credito')->nullable();
        $table->string('creditofecha')->nullable();
        $table->double('creditototal')->nullable();
```

ya que todas las tablas se relaciona con algo en común y no con llaves foránea la consulta va así

```
SELECT nombre,codigo,numerotalonario,estadocredito,creditofecha
FROM creditos,clientes,fee_detail
where creditos.clientes = clientes.id
AND clientes.id = fee_detail.fee_id
AND creditofecha BETWEEN CURDATE() and CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y añado el codigo small box

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]